# Remove Property name and use the value instead

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```js
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permission": "X",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "permission": "Y",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "permission": "Z",
      "value": "false"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to manipulate this JSON, so the output will look like the following:

```js
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "X" : ""
    },
    {
      "Y" : "false"
    },
    {
      "Z" : "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Parse it, turn it into a bunch of dictionaries, and [serialize them](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var json="{\"permissions\":[{\"permission\":\"X\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"permission\":\"Y\",\"value\":\"false\"},{\"permission\":\"Z\",\"value\":\"false\"}]}";

var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

var dict = jsonDeserialized.permissions.ToDictionary( x=>x.permission,x=>x.value);

var result = new { permissions = new Dictionary<string, string>[] {dict}};
var resultJson= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Output

```
{"permissions":[{"X":"","Y":"false","Z":"false"}]}
```

classes:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Permission> permissions { get; set; }
}
public class Permission
{
      public string permission { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```